# How to acquire binary log with the standard Azure Devops DotNet build task and have it attached to the build as an artifact with YAML build?

Tags: build, azure-devops

So far I have been using my own build Powershell script to build my code. Why? Because I like to have a binary log when a diag build is requested and have it attached to the build as an artifact.

But now that I use YAML I would like to use more of the standard tasks available with Azure DevOps. Namely the DotNet Build task. But I do not see how can I make it generate the binary log and attach to the build without writing a custom script anyway. I want it to work transparently - triggering a diag build (i.e. `System.Debug` is true) should do two things:

1. Pass `-bl:TheBinaryLogFilePath` to the dotnet build
2. Attach `TheBinaryLogFilePath` to the build as an artifact.

Is it possible in a straightforward manner without writing a custom script (otherwise not worth using the standard task anyway)?

Answer (score 0):

You dont have control over what changes when you do a debug build. and this is probably something that won't ever happen automatically because I dont see a reason why\how Microsoft would implement something that alters how my apps are being built.

As for the standard task, you can pass additional arguments to it using the `arguments:` property.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops#yaml-snippet

then you'd have to instruct publish artifacts task to pick up that binary folder path as well. thats it.

if you want to have conditions - fine, use conditions:

```
  - ${{ if eq($(System.Debug), 'true') }}:
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: build
      inputs:
        command: build
        publishWebProjects: false
        zipAfterPublish: false
        modifyOutputPath: false
        projects: xxx
        arguments: |
          -bl:TheBinaryLogFilePath
```

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on the statement "I dont see a reason why\how Microsoft would implement something that alters how my apps are being built." I do not understand how building with binary logs alters the way apps are being built. It is the same as claiming that changing the build verbosity alters the way apps are built. So, I am a bit confused here.

Comment: You suggest a certain approach. I think it is rather complicated to do it in YAML, but I may be missing something. Could you show a YAML code snippet for what you are suggesting?

Comment: well, its simple. I'm the one who created the pipeline the way it is. Why would I want somebody alter it for me? I wouldn't. Also, how do you imagine microsoft doing this for all the possible tools that exist there? do they parse all the scripts tasks you have and attempt to alter them for you? why? I've linked the article describing the schema for the task, you just need to add 1 property to the task, thats it.

Comment: There is a misunderstanding here. I do not want to change the task. I want to understand how to pass it the flags to generate the binary log when diag build is requested. That means when `$(System.Debug)` is `true` I want to pass `/bl:SomePath` and then publish it. My point is that I do not see how to do it with the current implementation of the task conveniently. You are suggesting a way, I think it is cumbersome, but please, show your snippet, maybe I am wrong.